# Python POST api giving error. Logs not found

Tags: python, rest, api, amazon-web-services, post

I am new with python. I have a POST api in python deployed on AWS using steps from the below mentioned link.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

The api is giving internal server error and the logs are not getting printed. Is there a directory which I'm missing or can I print the logs somehow?

Also if someone can help with what could be the possible issue with the API :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#!flask/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy
import sys,os
import codecs
import json
import phonetics
import transliteration
import jellyfish
import traceback
from pyjarowinkler import distance
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import panphon.distance
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS


def obj_dict(obj):
    return obj.__dict__

# logFile = open('log.txt','a')

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/todo/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET''POST'])
def get_tasks():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "done with get request"

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try :
            content = request.get_json()
            with codecs.open('words.txt', 'a') as file:
                for line in content['words']:
                    file.write("\n"+line.encode('utf-8'))

        except Exception:
            with open('log.txt','a') as logger:
                logger.write("At "+str(datetime.now())+" "+traceback.format_exc())
                logger.write("\n\n")

        return "done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt',level=logging.DEBUG)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = False)
```

NOTE: The other imports are for some other purpose. I need the POST API to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `debug = True`

**For example**

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt',level=logging.DEBUG)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = True)`

Also you don't need to import logging as you can use flask's logger which should be accessible using `app.logger`

If this is production then `debug=True` is not recommended. 
Flask considers ERROR as the default logging level if you do not set up log level 
So you might try setting the log level using `app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_tasks():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "done with get request"

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try :
            content = json.loads(request.get_data())
            with codecs.open('words.txt', 'a') as file:
                for line in content['words']:
                    file.write("\n"+line.encode('utf-8'))

        except Exception:
            with open('log.txt','a') as logger:
                logger.write("At "+str(datetime.now())+" "+traceback.format_exc())
                logger.write("\n\n")

        return "done"
```

Comment: Already tried it but logs are getting printed when I run it locally but not on AWS

Comment: on AWS are you running it with uwsgi or standalone?

Comment: running it using uwsgi. I have posted the link of the digital ocean blog I followed to run it.

Comment: Okay I will try to recreate the issue using the code above. Also I noticed that the the `route` `method` should be `['GET', 'POST']` There is a missing comma.

Comment: @techinjection I have updated my answer above try giving it a shot.

Comment: there is already a comma in the route method. It's shown in the above code no.

Comment: @techinjection No, I don't see it in the code you have posted. This is what I see `methods=['GET''POST']`
Did you try the updated answer?